# Why does VS keep insisting that another right paren is expected?

Tags: c#, boolean

This code:

```
private bool ValToEnterIsValid(string ACandidateVal) {
  return ((ACandidateVal == "1") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum1.Text)) ||
         ((ACandidateVal == "2") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum2.Text)) ||
     ((ACandidateVal == "3") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum3.Text));
}
```

...as well as this code:

```
private bool ValToEnterIsValid(string ACandidateVal) {
  return (((ACandidateVal == "1") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum1.Text)) ||
          ((ACandidateVal == "2") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum2.Text)) ||
      ((ACandidateVal == "3") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum3.Text)));
}
```

...causes VS to say, ") expected" - no matter how many right parens I add, trying to humor it!

Comment: Start on the left. Every time you see a (, raise a finger. When you see ), put a finger down. If you ever try to lower a finger when there are non raised, you have too many close parens. If you are done and you still have fingers raised, you have too few close parens.

Comment: +1 because `trying to humor it!` made me laugh.

Comment: That's basically what I normally do, but for whatever reason I was having a "blind spot" there... I normally just count to myself: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0 -ah! or ...oh, no! My "Oh, No" failed me this time.

Comment: Code like this is hard to read and is very prone to errors (hence the post on here trying to figure out why it doesn't work).  I would recommend breaking down each condition into it's own line and evaluating like that.  It makes the code easier to write, maintain, and troubleshoot later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your parentheses on each line are unbalanced. Also, you have extraneous parens because of the way precedence works; I'd write it as

```
private bool ValToEnterIsValid(string ACandidateVal) {
  return (ACandidateVal == "1" && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum1.Text)) ||
         (ACandidateVal == "2" && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum2.Text)) ||
         (ACandidateVal == "3" && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum3.Text));
}
```

Also, is there a reason you're using three variables instead of an array?

Comment: Oh, duh, I forgot the IsNullOrWhiteSpace() jazz!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are missing a ) on every part of the if:

```
private bool ValToEnterIsValid(string ACandidateVal) {
  return (( (ACandidateVal == "1") && 
            (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum1.Text)) ) ||
          ( (ACandidateVal == "2") && 
            (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum2.Text)) ) ||
          ( (ACandidateVal == "3") && 
            (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum3.Text)) )
         );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing extra ")" at the end of each !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace comparisons:

This code works:

```
        private bool ValToEnterIsValid(string ACandidateVal) {
          return (
              (ACandidateVal == "1") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum1.Text)) ||
              (ACandidateVal == "2") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum1.Text)) ||
              (ACandidateVal == "3") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum1.Text))
             );
        }

        private bool ValToEnterIsValid(string ACandidateVal) {
          return (
              ((ACandidateVal == "1") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum1.Text))) ||
              ((ACandidateVal == "2") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum2.Text))) ||
              ((ACandidateVal == "3") && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPhoneNum3.Text)))
              );
        }
```